# Video player with frame by frame, holding a key, like slow motion, backward and forward?

Tags: windows, media-player, video-player

If I watch a video in Media Player Classic, and hold the forward arrow, then it goes frame by frame smoothly like in slow motion.. Though backwards is jolty, it doesn't update while you hold the left arrow button it only updates when you release the left arrow button,  and Media player classic is no longer under development. So i'm interested in alternatives that do that.

VLC has the key "E" to go forward frames, and when held, it's smooth like slow motion, but it doesn't have a key to go back frames!!!!

And I want good speed of it too.. I tried SM Player, but it's too slow.. VLC has a good speed but only forwards. Quicktime had a good speed though is no longer supported. And MPC while not so bad, is a bit jolty going backwards, and is not in development anymore.

Comment: Reading between the lines, you want that player for Windows? Any price limit?

Comment: maybe $60 limit?

Comment: I added the Windows tag, because I'm guessing Izzy is correct with his reading between the lines.  If that's incorrect, please delete the tag and add the correct OS tag.  Also, if correct, can you add "Windows" in the question somewhere, as well as your price range (that way the info is in the question instead of the comments)? Good question, by the way.  Thanks!

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket so far the question izzy asked was pointless.. nothing has been suggested for Any OS, and at any price!  I am interested in for Windows, though if somebody wants to comment that linux has some things then that's a bit interesting.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket and if nobody had any answers but there was something for $500 that did it then i'd be curious. I don't want to limit things too much. It's not like there's tons of software that do what I asked for anyway.

Answer (score 1):

VLC is still a great option without a "Frame Skip Backwards"

In TOOLS / PREFERENCE / INTERFACE / HOTKEYS
You can set Very Short Jump Length from 3 seconds to 1
[image: VLC Hotkey Settings]

Now useing "**E**" to Frame Skip Forwards
If you go to far, "**SHIFT + Left Arrow**" will go back 1 second
On a video running 23 Frames Per Second, it will take 23 "**E**" push's
to skip 1 second

Comment: "E" moves a frame, but only works forwards. So I'd have to use "very short jump" to go backwards(one second smallest unit unfortunately), and E to go forwards.

Comment: @barlop So it sounds like the user will go back 1 second by pressing `Shift+LeftArrow`, and then forward 1/23 of a second with each `E` keystroke.  Does that somehow fulfill your desire for a backwards slow motion?  I'm not understanding how that is backwards slow motion, but perhaps I'm just not understanding what's being recommended.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket indeed it doesn't fulfill what I want.. it's not an answer and it should be a comment, it just makes VLC less bad! He might not have rep to comment